Modified Duration vs. Real-World Bond Price and Yield Changes
We know that modified duration at time $t$ of a bond with maturity $n$ is defined as:
$$
D_{nt} = - \frac{1}{P_{nt}} \frac{\partial{P_{nt}}}{\partial y_{nt}}
$$
And the definition of a derivative is:
$$
\frac{\partial{P_{nt}}}{\partial y_{nt}} = \lim_{\Delta y_{nt} \rightarrow 0} \frac{P_{nt}(y_{nt} + \Delta y) - P_{nt}(y_{nt})}{\Delta y_{nt}}
$$
I understand that $\Delta y_{nt}$ is a small change in $y_{nt}$, a change in yield at  the same maturity $n$ and time $t$. However, in real life, time passes and maturity decreases. That is, it would be more realistic to talk about something like this:
$$
\frac{\Delta P_{nt}}{\Delta y_{nt}} = \frac{P_{n-1, t+1} - P_{nt}}{y_{n-1, t+1} - y_{nt}}
$$
Is this a thing? Am I missing something?

Sensitivity measure (also Greeks in options) are usually always all else equal measures. That said, you can use all sorts of measures, and some do incorporate more shifts, like Bartlett's delta.

Duration measures how sensitive today's bond price is to today's yield. This gives you important information about the bond, esp. when you want to compare a few bonds. No one claims that duration is the measure that applies to every conceivable real life situation. Besides: as I interpret your definitions: to know $P_{n-1,t+1}$ (tomorrow's bond price) one would need supernatural abilities.

Great guys, thank you very much! Makes sense.
